# Url Shortening in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, url-shortener

I have one url like *www.example.com/user/12345*

I want to create a short url for above url like *www.ex.com/12345*. Both will display same page.

Note: i want to create short url with different domain name eg. *www.ex.com*

I tried this rule with url manager, but it doesn't work.

```
array(
    'http://www.mfd.com/<param:\d+>/*' => '/user/12345',
)
```

Comment: yes, both domain points to same app.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this, you have to place it as the first rule:

```
'<id:\d+>' => 'user/view',
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel... But i want to use different domain for short url. is it possible in YII?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure in your **Url Manager** in config file like this -

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        'rohit'=> 'site/user/rohit',
    )
)
```

i have implemented in my yii project, see demo - [yii.at](http://yii.at)